# Getting token in card to retrieve user image from profile

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, bearer-token, card

I am working on adapting a bot ([Expert Finder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/microsoft-teams-apps-expertfinder/microsoft-teams-apps-expertfinder/)) and want to retrieve the users photo from their SharePoint profile to send back as a base64 string to the client. I have the image URL in SharePoint but when I try and download the image from the profile url, I get

"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10501:...."

Can anyone help with the code to generate a token or bearer string? There is a TokenHelper class in the solution.

Thanks in advance,
Jake.

UPDATE: I made some progress on this. I was able to use the tokenHelper.GetUserTokenAsync method from the TokenHelper class and get a bearer token.

Next I am accessing the following url: https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&username=john.doe@mytenant.com

When I use the url in the browser, it brings up the users image. But when I run it through the bot code or even in standalone code, I only get a silhouette named PersonPlaceholder.96x96x32.png. Any idea why I am not getting the actual image back?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why I was getting the silhouette on the sharepoint url. So I switched to the Graph API instead and was able to get the image back successfully.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('john.doe@test.com')/photos('48x48')/$value](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users(%27john.doe@test.com%27)/photos(%2748x48%27)/$value)

Full Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0